# Changing UIView Frame at Runtime

Tags: ios

I am implementing a really simple piece of code in which a user clicks a button and I try to change the frame of a UITextField. I have an IBOutlet connection for firstNameTextField. When I user clicks the button I execute the following code:

```
self.firstNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.firstNameTextField.frame.size.width, self.firstNameTextField.frame.size.height);
```

Keeping in mind that the initial position of firstNameTextField was at x = 20; y = 96.

**How do I change the firstNameTextField frame at runtime?**

UPDATE: It might be because I am using Auto Layout so I cannot change the frame.

Thanks,

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: @Alladinian Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yep... so I guess the problem is that your textfield doesn't go to (0,0) right ? Where do you set the frame (inside which method) ?

Comment: If you're using autolayout, consider modifying the constraints.

Comment: I set the frame inside the UIButton onTouchInside method. The method is invoked correctly! But the frame is not set. Maybe it is because of Autolayout.

Comment: @johndoe John and did *you* even proofread it before posting? It just doesn't make sense. The code in the question already "changes the frame at runtime".

Comment: @H2CO3 Please read the question!! It clearly says that even though I am changing the frame it is not working.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank God, I thought I was the only one...

Comment: I guess I need to start writing in all CAPS for you old people :)

Comment: Have you verified that `self.firstNameTextField` is not `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! Just verified it is not null. As mentioned I will try messing with the constraints to change the location of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Make `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints == YES`,

Then call `self.firstNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.firstNameTextField.frame.size.width, self.firstNameTextField.frame.size.height);`

They are translated into constraints that can be satisfied with the rest of your constraints.

Read **[Adopting Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH15-SW1)** section for more details

Comment: I just did that and it did not work! No changes seems to be happening.

Comment: Read Adopting Auto Layout section for more details,,, i have included the link in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `IBOutlet` connections for the constraints that you want to change, and then you can change the `constant` property on the constraints in your code.

Another solution would be disabling auto layout, if you're not doing anything that specifically needs it. But if it's otherwise working for you with it on, you probably wouldn't want to change it in case it does break something, and it's probably just easier to implement my first suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! But that did not work either! When I change the constraint it messes everything up! I am surprised that a simple thing to change the frame is so difficult with Auto Layout.

Comment: Which constraints did you try changing, and what exactly did it mess up?